# Adding search function within form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am adding a search function within another form. I would like to search through the things within the other form.

**Interest_index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :interest, url: interest_index_path do |f| %>
    <p class="col-md-8" align="left"><%= f.submit "Save Schedule", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"%></p>
    <br>
    <div class="field form-group col-lg-12">
        <h1><%= f.label :interests, "Schedule" %></h1>
        <br>
        <div class="row inline">
         <%= form_tag interest_index_path, method: :get do %>
          <p>
          <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-7" id="one">
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search" %>
          </div>
          <div id="two">
            <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
          </div>
          </p>
        <% end %>
       </div> 

       <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
        <div class="field">
          <p><h4><%= f.check_box :interests, {:multiple => true}, subject.id, nil %><%= subject.name %></h4></p>
        </div> 
       <% end %>
     </div> 
<% end %>
```

I have the search form within a bigger form to search through the subjects which will be chosen and then submitted with the main form. I have tried using basic search as i a new to rails but it does not work.

I think usually to have a form within a form you would need to make nested attributes, but this being a search form I am not sure how to do that or whether that would work.

Also the way i have it set up is I have created a lot of *subjects* which will be displayed under the *interests* index. Under interests the user picks the subjects of their interests

*here are the controllers and models*

**Interests_controller**
    class InterestController < ApplicationController

```
 def index
   if params[:query].present?
     @subjects = Subject.search(params[:query], load: true)
   else
     @subjects = Subject.all.sort_by(&:name)
   end
 end

 def create
   current_user.interests = params[:interests].to_json
   if current_user.save
   else
     flash[:danger] = "Something went wrong!"
   end
     redirect_to interest_index_path
   end

end
```

** Interest Model**

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
searchkick

include Tire::Model::Search
include Tire::Model::Callbacks

def self.search(search)
    if search
        where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}")
    else
        scoped
    end
end
end
```

**Subject model**

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :posts
 has_many :users, through: :posts
 validates_presence_of :name
 validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

**Subject_controller**

```
class SubjectController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @subject = Subject.all.includes(:posts => [:user])
   @interests_array = []
   if current_user.interests != "null"
     JSON.parse(current_user.interests).each do |f|
       if Subject.find(f)
         @interests_array.push(Subject.find(f))
       end
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, there was no need for nested forms. I was also working with the wrong model.